# Want to replace browser scroll bar with my own

Tags: jquery, html

I have one problem in my home page design. Problem is that I don't want a scroll bar which is provided by the browser. I have created my own scroll bar so please give me hint how can do this thing?

1. Can I use jQuery?
2. Can I do this through HTML?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Styling the scrollbar isn't part of any standard and it's implemented differently in different browsers. You'll therefore want to use some JavaScript code to ensure your styles are applied consistently across browsers. Check out [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/), a jQuery plugin.

Comment: I just tried it and found it pretty good (+ easy to customize the look).

Answer (score 3):

I got it

```
body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 10px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}


html {
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: transparent;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-button:start:decrement,
::-webkit-scrollbar-button:end:increment {
    height: 30px;
    display: block;
    background-color: transparent;
}



::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
    background-color: #3b3b3b;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #666;
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Comment: Good code & fine scrollbar, but some note to back it in the place for Mozilla: `@-moz-document url-prefix() {body { right: 0 !important; }}
`

Answer (score 2):

You can either [change the color settings of the browser's scrollbar](http://rainbow.arch.scriptmania.com/tools/scrollbar/colour_scrollbar_generator.html), or limit content to an element within your page and create a Javascript script (possibly with the use of jQuery) to navigate that element if its content overflows.

A [Google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=jquery+scrollbar&aq=f&aqi=g4g-s1g5&aql=&oq=) of the later contains many tutorials that should be able to help you.